# Use aliases for column names when setting Models in sequelize

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I am new to sequelize and I try to implemented in an existing node/express project.

So far, I have this simple Model and it works when I query it

```
  const User = sequelize.define('AppUser', {
    // attributes
    idUser: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    } 
  });
```

So the table named AppUser that has a primary key named idUser is now the User Model.

The id of the User Model is idUser, same as the AppUser table.

If I change the mapping to another table, say webUser and the id is webId, I have to change from idUser to webUser in all my queries. What is the point of mapping in one place then?

I should be able to do something like (pseudocode)

```
  const User = sequelize.define('webUser', {
    // attributes
    id AS idUser or webUser or whatever: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    } 
  });
```

What am I missing here , about the column mapping?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use **field** prop:

AppUser

```
// attributes
    id: {
      field: 'idUser',
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    }
```

WebUser

```
// attributes
    id: {
      field: 'webId',
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    }
```